# onAfter event in quicksearch plugin for jQuery called too soon

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, quick-search

I'm using the quicksearch plugin for jQuery and generally it works well. I've added a function to the onAfter event which gets called but I have found that it is called before the style attribute on the row has been set to "display: none"

Is there another event or a way to hook into another event that will fire after this attribute has been changed?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem with the onAfter event you were. The solution is to modify the plugin and move the line where options.onAfter is getting called into the earlier setTimeout call that actually does the processing for the search.

I'm a novice javascript coder myself. I found the solution on this page ..
[artiomchi.blogspot.com](http://artiomchi.blogspot.com/2009/08/jquery-tablesorter-quicksearch-headache.html) where someone was trying to integrate this quicksearch plugin with the tablesorter plugin.

Hope this helps!
Stephen